Cantonese (jyutping) pronunciation of 援 (wun4 or jyun4 or both)?
Cantodict has a number of entries that indicate 援 can be pronounced jyun4 as well as wun4. Is this correct, because I've heard people say it's always wun4?
Here are the current relevant entries in Cantodict:
援: wun4/jyun4
技術支援: gei6 seot6 zi1 wun4/jyun4
支援: zi1 wun4/jyun4
援助: jyun4 zo6; wun4 zo6
增援: zang1 wun4/jyun4
核支援: hat6 zi1 wun4/jyun4
軍事援助: gwan1 si6 jyun4 zo6 (note: jyun4 only)
援手: wun4 sau2; jyun4 sau2
外援: ngoi6 wun4/jyun4


援 = 雨元切 in Middle Chinese, and so would "regularly" become jyun4 in Cantonese. But colloquialisms and irregularities do become standard over time!

援

Jyutping wun4 is standard reading; jyun4 is variant.

Almost everyone pronounces 援 as /wun4/ colloquially
In day-to-day life, 援 is pronounced as /jyun4/ mostly when it is literary, for example, reading from a script in the news, but in most cases, reading as /wun4/ is still preferred)

Thanks. Is there anything specific about 軍事援助 or should that represent 援 the same as elsewhere (i.e. wun4 colloquially, juan4 written)?

Sometimes people just want to make it sound more literary thus giving a formal feel, Also 援助 in 軍事援/wun4/助 sounds like a verb; in 軍事援/yun4/助 sounds like a noun
